# what does Valgrind summary mean?

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran, openmp, valgrind

I run my fortran code with Valgrind and this is the summary:

```
==7966== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7966==     in use at exit: 13,254 bytes in 19 blocks
==7966==   total heap usage: 340 allocs, 321 frees, 75,007 bytes allocated
==7966== 
==7966== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7966==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7966==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7966==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7966==    still reachable: 13,254 bytes in 19 blocks
==7966==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7966== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==7966== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==7966== 
==7966== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7966== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

1. Is everything OK?

2. `==7966==   total heap usage: 340 allocs, 321 frees, 75,007 bytes allocated`

It means some memories are not deallocated? All my variables are static.

3. My serial code works well, but when I make it parallel with OpenMP and for large data the `segmentation fault` occurs. may these memories cause this problem?

edit: I run the code with

```
valgrind --leak-check=yes ./a.out
```

and this is the summary:

```
==9825== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9825==    at 0x41630D9: log (w_log.c:28)
==9825==    by 0x804D052: MAIN__ (main.f90:225)
==9825==    by 0x804D128: main (main.f90:231)
==9825== 
==9825== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==9825==    at 0x4158E88: __ieee754_log (e_log.S:16)
==9825==    by 0x41630EF: log (w_log.c:42)
==9825==    by 0x804D052: MAIN__ (main.f90:225)
==9825==    by 0x804D128: main (main.f90:231)
==9825== 
==9825== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9825==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9825==   total heap usage: 12,023 allocs, 12,023 frees, 96,007,152 bytes allocated
==9825== 
==9825== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9825== 
==9825== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9825== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==9825== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

I can not find the problem, this is the line 225

```
       free_energy(d) = -log(abs(correlation_fun(d)))
```

Comment: I'm unconvinced the supplied answers are sufficient. Valgrind typically doesn't throw errors when assigning an uninitialized variable, although the `abs` function may include an actual conditional jump.
If you run `valgrind` on a code compiled with`-O3` or other optimizations the line numbers can get screwed up. What are your compile-time options?

Comment: I used `-g `. Is `-03` a flag? my compiler does not recognize it.

Comment: `-O3` is a flag; you're using the number zero but you should be using the letter O as in oscar. If you're just running with `-g`, though, the line numbers should be ok. So I guess that all or some of `correlation_fun` is uninitialized, as others have said.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the usage if uninitialized variables. You have to find out which one is it and make sure it has a meaningful value. *Nothing more can be said without the full code.* Very probably the value of `d` was not defined properly.

The still reachable memory is normally OK. That is **not** a leak. Typically, these are allocatable variables which you did not deallocate. They may be in a module or in the main program or declared `save` anywhere else. They are not deallocated automatically when the program finishes and it is normally not a problem.

A real memory leak which would cause a problem is when you lose a pointer to some memory and then you have no way to deallocate it. If you do that repeatedly, you may waste a lot of memory. That however looks differently in valgrind. You then see `definitely lost`, `indirectly lost` or `possibly lost`.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are leaking memory according to this line: ==7966==    still reachable: 13,254 bytes in 19 blocks
2. Try rerunning with --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all  as suggested and compiling with compile flags to track which variables are being leaked. Even if variables are static, they still leak memory if they are heap allocated.
3. Segmentation faults are best debugged with gdb, but this memory leak could cause it.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Can you explain more about how to understand which variables are being leaked? I am new in programming

Comment: When you compile the program, run g++ -g (stuff) to get line numbers in valgrind. Afterwards, when you run valgrind  --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all  (exec name), you will be able to find which variables are leaking memory based on what line(s) valgrind gives.

Comment: No, this is not a leak. Not deallocated allocatable `save` (static) variables are not a leak and typically are not harmful. They cannot grow in time and they are reclaimed by the OS when the program ends.

Comment: When I answered this question, there was no extra information on the uninitialized values :)